How many equilateral triangle in a equilateral triangle?
If you lay out an equilateral triangle completely with other smaller equilateral triangles, how many equilateral triangles can you find in total? I wanted to find a general formula for this classic puzzle. I couldn't find anything about it on the Internet, maybe you have an idea.
Here are my approaches and attempts to solve the problem. In the end, however, I do not get a satisfactory solution
I first divided the outer triangle into n rows and then counted all the smallest triangles ($n^2$).
For the triangles that consist of the smaller triangles and point upwards, we get: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{k}j$.
Now let's get to my actual question. If you choose n>3, you get another triangle. This one now points downwards. In order to take this into account, we need: $\sum_{k=1}^{n-3}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-5}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-7}k + …$. If n-b<0 then the sum is 0 as well.
So how can we simplify these series and is this approach to determining the number of triangles even correct?

How could you construct an equilateral triangle from the given grid?

Hint. Every line has $k$ upward triangles and $k-1$ downward triangles.

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!
